# What does the term `functions objects` in Javascript actually mean?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

After reading a lot, I still don't quite understand the term `function objects` in JS. From what I have read, following are my interpretations. Please correct if I'm wrong.

```
function myfunc(x){
 return x;
}
```

**Interpretation**:
`myfunc` is a `function object` auto created by JS interpreter internally whenever a new function like `myfunc` is declared as shown above.

```
var myObj = new myfunc();
var mynewObj = new myfunc();
```

**Interpretation**: `myObj` and `mynewObj` are instances(objects) of `myfunc` thus can be said to be a `function objects`

Are my interpretations correct. Any other examples of function objects?

thanks

bt

Comment: Have a look at [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Interpretation: `myfunc` is a function object auto created by JS interpreter internally whenever a new function like `myfunc` is declared as shown above.

Almost, but not quite. `myfunc` is an identifer that *refers* to (points to) a function created by the JavaScript engine.<sup>1</sup> That function is an object, because all functions are objects in JavaScript. You could call it a "function object" if you like; most people would just call it a "function." (In JavaScript "function" and "function object" are synonyms.)

> ```
> var myObj = new myfunc();
> var mynewObj = new myfunc();
> ```
>
> Interpretation: `myObj` and `mynewObj` are instances(objects) of `myfunc` thus can be said to be a `function objects`

No, they're not function objects. They're just objects. They are indeed `instanceof myfunc` which means that the object `myfunc.prototype` points to is in their prototype chain, but it's not correct at all to call them "function objects" because they aren't functions.

---

<sup>1</sup> "JavaScript engine" - This is the term I use in preference to "JavaScript interpreter" because any modern JavaScript engine is a just-in-time-compiler plus runtime environment, not an interpreter. It's a subtle distinction.

---

In a comment, Jamie Dixon mentions the `Function` function. It's just a function that creates functions based on source code strings. There are virtually no use cases for it in modern JavaScript (just as there are virtually no use cases for `eval` in modern JavaScript).

Comment: There's also a Function object (capital F) that can be used in place of the function value declaration i.e. `var foo = new Function(args, body);`. MSDN (heh) refers to these as function value (function) and Function object.

Comment: @JamieDixon: Yeah, well, MSDN, nuff said. I intentionally didn't bring `Function` into the mix here to avoid confusion.

Comment: @TJ Crowder, if `myfunc` can also be referred as `function objects` that means that object has been created i.e it's already been instantiated and suppose `myfunc` is definition is: `function myfunc() {
 return this.x ="Great fun"; }

Then `myfunc.x;` should output `Great fun` but the output is `undefined`. The output means the object `myfunc` has not been instantiated.

Comment: @bTech: *"suppose myfunc is definition is: `function myfunc() { return this.x ="Great fun"; }` Then `myfunc.x;` should output `Great fun`"* No, it shouldn't. `this` inside `myfunc` is not (normally) a reference to the function itself. If you use `new myfunc()`, `this` will refer to a new object (which isn't a function). If you do `myfunc()` (no `new`), in strict mode `this` will be `undefined` and in loose mode `this` will be the global object, but either way it's not the same as `myfunc` so `this.x = 'Great fun'` does not create a property on `myfunc`.

Comment: so `this` inside `myfunc` will be `undefined`? (JS default for variables that has not been assigned)` and does each instantiated object has it's own private 'this' variable that points to itself?

Comment: @bTech: *"so `this` inside `myfunc` will be `undefined`?"* Not necessarily, read my comment again. See also: [*How does the `this` keyword work?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work?rq=1)

Comment: @TJ Crowder: all constructor function's (actually all function's) `function.prototype` points to  `Object {}` (an object) which means they inherit prop/methods from `Object{}` so is this the reason all functions are said to be objects in JS?

Comment: @bTech: 1. No. Functions are objects because that's how the language is defined, it has nothing to do with their `prototype` property. The `prototype` property on the function can be anything the author of the function wants it to be (including `null`). If it's an object, and if you use `new` with the function, the object that gets created by `new` will use the object `prototype` referred to as its `[[Prototype]]` (the object it inherits things from), but that's completely unrelated to functions being objects.